# Storing pointers to static variables

Tags: c++, unit-testing, static-order-fiasco

I've created a unit test framework for c++ which I want to port to C later and I've come across a problem where a unit test simply won't run. Unit tests are created in .cpp files and only one .cpp file should run all the tests.

To simplify a bit, this is how a test is typically created:

## main.cpp

```
#define UNIT_TEST_IMPL // or whatever
#include "unit_test.hpp"

int main()
{
    for(const auto& test : tests_queue)
        test->run();
    return 0;
}
```

## unit_test.hpp

```
#pragma once

struct Base
{
protected:
    Base() = delete;
    Base(Base* ptr);

public:
    virtual void run() = 0;
};

#if defined(UNIT_TEST_IMPL)

#include <vector>

std::vector<Base*> tests_queue;

Base::Base(Base* ptr)
{
    tests_queue.push_back(ptr);
}

#endif
```

## test.cpp

```
#include "unit_test.hpp"

#include <iostream>

struct Test : Base
{
    Test()
        : Base(this)
    {}

    void run() override
    {
        std::cout << "new test" << std::endl;
    }

};

struct Test2 : Base
{
    Test2()
        : Base(this)
    {}

    void run() override
    {
        std::cout << "new test2" << std::endl;
    }
};

static Test test;
static Test2 test2;
```

The question is: why is it not running the tests defined in test.cpp (if I create tests in the main.cpp file they run perfectly fine)? My guess is that the problem lies in the way I am storing Base pointers but I don't know.
The compiler is g++ 6.4.0

Comment: `Base(this)`. Funny, what not have `Base::Base()
{
    tests_queue.push_back(this);
}`

Comment: And how would the tests be stored if I do so?

Comment: See my answer which also clean that part.

Answer (score 4):

static-initialization-order-fiasco in action:

Initialization order of global across translation units is unspecified, so if `test`, `test2` are instantiated before `tests_queue`, the later initialization would destroy the registration.

One possible correction:

```
#pragma once

struct Base
{
protected:
    Base();

public:
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    virtual void run() = 0;
};

#if defined(UNIT_TEST_IMPL) // Should be defined only once.

#include <vector>

std::vector<Base*>& get_tests_queue()
{
    static std::vector<Base*> tests_queue;
    return tests_queue;
}

Base::Base()
{
    get_tests_queue().push_back(this);
}

#endif
```

so your main.cpp would be:

```
#define UNIT_TEST_IMPL // or whatever
#include "unit_test.hpp"

int main()
{
    for(const auto& test : get_tests_queue())
        test->run();
}
```

Your unitTests would be unmodified:

```
#include "unit_test.hpp"

#include <iostream>

struct Test : Base
{
    void run() override { std::cout << "new test" << std::endl; }
};

struct Test2 : Base
{
    void run() override { std::cout << "new test2" << std::endl; }
};

static Test test;
static Test2 test2;
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/H1VGMePem)

Comment: Ok...now at least I know where the problem is coming from. Found out something new today. Thank your for that! But how could I specify that order? Wrap that initialization somehow(eg: in a lambda that calls itself - or would it be the exact same thing)?

Comment: Oh, just saw the suggestion, sorry :))

Answer (score 0):

My bets go to some form of [Static Initialization Fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order)

Not sure about it, but you cannot count on global variables (your Test1 and Test2 variables defined in test.cpp being initalized befor Main runs.

As a rule of thumb avoid global variables if you can (and in this case, you probably can).

But mainly, your program should not make any assumption on initialization order of global/static variables. Here you are assuming the two globals are initialized before main. Possibly, they are not